# How to reference to other folders?

Tags: html

I have created a few html-pages and one CSS-page inside a folder (Webservice). At first I just used to reference to my CSS-page like this because they were in the same folder.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
```

Then I wanted to make it look more clean so I created separate folders for html and CSS within the already existing folder (Webservice). The new folders were named html and CSS. If I do it like down below it works, but I need to be able to access the files on other computers/devices as well.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="file:///Users/home/Desktop/Webservice/css/style.css">
```

It does not work to do like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
```

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use ../ inside the html folder to go to the parent folder.
And then you can access the css folder so your link will look like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css">
```

By using a relative path, it will work on your other computer.

Comment: If you use different folder depths, one subfolder is enough, then you are doomed with this solution.  better use absolute path like  href="/css/style.css"

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the `relative path` to your CSS style from HTML file.
To view more https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/supplement/pathnames-explained-absolute-relative-unc-and-url.htm